# Returning array elements according to their types

Tags: php

I'm reading book about php, and here is task to print elements of array depends on their type;
So i created array `$arr = array (5, 'str', 4, 'str1', -100, 10);`, and then using `foreach` statement i tried to print elements that are integer

```
foreach ($arr1 as is_integer($arrelem)) 
    {
        print $arrelem;

    }
```

But this gives me an error`Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in`.
I'm sure there is something wrong with algorithm, but i need advice on how to understand these  alhorighms

Comment: you can resolve that by searching how foreach works in PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I already did that, i can print all elements of array using this statement, but the algorithm of how to print only some of elements, is not clear for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foreach ($arr1 as is_integer($arrelem))` is not allowed

Write it like so:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $arrelem) {
    if (is_integer($arrelem)) {
        print "int:" . $arrelem;
    } else if (is_string($arrelem)) {
        print "string:" . $arrelem;
    } else {
        print "other:" . $arrelem;
    }
}
```

If this is for debugging you can also use `var_dump`, which will give you the *type* and *value* of a variable.

Comment: can i do like these?
    `foreach ($arr1 as $array_elem) { 
    if (is_integer($array_elem)) {
        print $array_elem;
    }
    print $arrelem; 
elseif (is_string($array_elem)) {print $array_elem;} 
}`

Answer (score 3):

```
$integerValues = array_filter($array1,'is_integer');
$booleanValues = array_filter($array1,'is_bool');
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct syntax, after keyword as you may place only name of variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example

```
$arr = array(5,'str',4,'str1',- 100,10);
```

Example 1 -  **Waygood**

```
foreach ($arr as $var) {
    print $var . ": ";
    echo gettype($var), "\n";
}
```

Example 2

```
foreach ( $arr as $var ) {
    print $var . ": ";
    if (is_integer($var)) {
        if ($var < 0) {
            print "Negative Integer \n";
        } else {
            print "Positive Integer \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or use gettype() instead of all the IF statements

Comment: +1 Waygood ... i would update my answer with a better example